# Template class with std::enable_if_t, static const member initialization

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, enable-if

Okay, after searching myself half to death and not finding any answer that actually seemed to work I gotta ask:

Say I've got a class (contrived example, but hopefully good enough for now)

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t< MyConditional<T>::value >>
class MyClass
{
public:
    static const MyClass ZeroInited;

    MyClass(int x, int y) 
        : m_X(x)
        , m_Y(Y) 
    {
    }

    ...
};
```

How do I properly initialize `ZeroInited`*? The correct syntax just eludes me (or maybe I'm just too tired), and letting tools "Create Implementation" does not produce correct output either. It's

Thanks everyone!

*) PS: in the templated case, not for a specialization. If I leave out the enable_if_t it's easy:

```
template <typename T> const MyClass<T> MyClass<T>::ZeroInited {0, 0};
```

but I can't figure out how to change it once enable_if_t comes into play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t< MyConditional<T>::value >>
```

is that you expect as second argument a `void` **value**, which doesn't exist.

- use

  ```
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t< MyConditional<T>::value, bool> = false>
  class MyClass{/*..*/};
  ```

  and

  ```
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t< MyConditional<T>::value, bool > B>
  const MyClass<T, B> MyClass<T, B>::ZeroInited{0, 0};
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pg6atB)
- or

  ```
  template <typename T, typename /*U*/ = std::enable_if_t< MyConditional<T>::value>>
  class MyClass{/*..*/};
  ```

  and

  ```
  template <typename T, typename U>
  const MyClass<T, U> MyClass<T, U>::ZeroInited{0, 0};
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/VWoXQP)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++17, you can declare `ZeroInited` `inline` and initialise it in the declaration (since this is then also a definition):

```
static const inline MyClass ZeroInited { 10, 20 };
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9ShViSB4I3dTafG1)

I'm not sure how you solve this in C++14 and earlier.

Comment: That's of course a solution, but I try to keep my interfaces (as in class declarations, not  the C# meaning) clean (pure declaration, no implementation), and put the implementations in an inl file. Thanks anyway, this is definitely a viable option.